# Table Layout is not working

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Hello i have used `Tablayout` and `viewpager` and `viewpager` contain `listview`  in my `fragement`.

I want to implement the functionalities to scroll tab layout also when i scroll list from `viewpager`

Here is my XMl file

**message_frag_layout.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/gray"
        app:tabBackground="@color/tabcolor"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    app:backgroundTint= "#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/edit" />
```

How to scroll tab layout also when I scroll `listview` from `viewpager`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try enclosing the whole layout inside a NestedScrollView. Although, in making such a layout, there is a potential for a lot of issues with scrolling if not handled correctly.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:id="@+id/nested_parent_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<!--  your layout goes here -->


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/gray"
    app:tabBackground="@color/tabcolor"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
    app:tabGravity="fill"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/viewpager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/fab"
app:backgroundTint= "#FFFFFF"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
android:src="@drawable/edit" />


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: i dont know where to place tha scrollview

Comment: Doing this allows your tablayout to go out of the screen and show contents placed below it if that is what you want :)

Comment: This will only happen if the content to be displayed i bigger than your screen though

Comment: how exactly do you want to scroll the tab layout? you can swipe left and right to change the tabs with viewpager. And the listview will scroll up and down. My layout allows to scroll the whole tab page out of screen showing content below the tablayout

Answer (score 1):

See this to learn to implement Tablayout with a viewpager.

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout

Now in each fragment displayed inside the Tab, you can put your listview.